# TSQL Stuff data

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql

I need to find a way to `Group By` some data in a specific way.

```
id  Number  FROM    TO
1   240     201710  201712
1   240     201712  201801
1   240     201801  201803
1   300     201803  201805
1   240     201805  999999
```

I need them grouped in this way:

```
id  TEXT
1   201710 - 201803: 240, 201803 - 20180: 300, 201805 - 999999: 240
```

My problem is to get the right grouping. It has to group row 1-3 and set `FROM` to `201710` and `TO` to `201803`. But I cant group by the number because it can change later again.

Any ideas?

The only idea i have is checking the FROM with THE FROM of the next row and set it to the previous FROM if the number matches. Then i could group by `id, number` and `FROM` and take the `MAX` of `TO`. But I really dont wan't to use a Cursor.

Here a testscript:

```
DECLARE @Test AS table
(
    customerid int,
    Number     int,
    DateFrom   int,
    DateTo     int
);

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES (1, 240, 201710, 201712),
       (1, 240, 201712, 201801),
       (1, 240, 201801, 201803),
       (1, 300, 201803, 201805),
       (1, 240, 201805, 999999);

SELECT t.customerid,
       t.Number,
       t.DateFrom,
       t.DateTo
FROM   @Test t;

SELECT   customerid,
         STUFF(
         (SELECT DISTINCT
                 ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(100), (t2.DateFrom)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar(100), (t2.DateTo)) + ' : '
                 + CONVERT(varchar(100), (t2.Number))
          FROM   @Test t2
         FOR XML PATH('')),
         1,
         2,
         '') AS Text
FROM     @Test t
WHERE t.customerid = t2.customerid
GROUP BY t.customerid;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.customerid,
           t.Number,
           t.DateFrom,
           t.DateTo,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (order by datefrom) - ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by number order by datefrom) grpCol
    FROM   @Test t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT customerid, 
           cast(MIN(datefrom) as varchar(10)) + ' - ' + cast(MAX(dateto) as varchar(10)) + ': ' + cast(number as varchar(10)) [text],
           MIN(datefrom) datefrom
    FROM cte c
    group by customerid, number, grpCol
)

SELECT customerid, 
       (select [text] + ', ' from cte2 where customerid = c.customerid order by datefrom for xml path('')) [text]
FROM cte2 c
GROUP BY customerid
```

Output:

```
customerid | text
1          | 201710 - 201803: 240, 201803 - 201805: 300, 201805 - 999999: 240,
```

Comment: Looks great! Solves the problem for sure. Thanks!

Comment: Somehow it doesnt work in my production data...do you know any possible reasons why it fails? the rownumbers are not sorted at all. I just have another cte in front of your cte's that provides the data

Comment: @Karsten93 What do you mean by doesn't work? Do you get errors? Or output is wrong? Clearly, if your data is of the same structure, as you posted here, there's no chance it won't work. So, your production data might be different.

Comment: Output is wrong. Data seem ok. i checked out and it already happens with a few data in the table. The Only difference i see is, that there are duplicated data in the production data, but i filtered them before.

Comment: INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES (1, 240, 201710, 201712),
    (1, 240, 201712, 201801),
    (1, 240, 201801, 201803),
    (1, 300, 201803, 201805),
    (1, 240, 201805, 999999),
(11 ,175, 201611, 201709),
(11 ,175, 201709, 201711),
(11 ,175, 201711, 201712),
(11 ,175, 201712, 201801),
(11 ,175, 201801, 201802)